# Populate UILabel in TableView Cell with returned JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I'm trying to pull the JSON data from fields "field_message_subject" and "field_message_body" to a table cell in my app. I'm using the following code to do it, and the data is returned successfully, but my app crashes and the label isn't populated. The crash error is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

**Viewcontroller.m**

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];


        NSDictionary *entityData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"] forKey:@"uid"];

        [DIOSEntity
         entityGet:entityData
         name:@"entity_message"
         eid:@"uid"
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id response) {
             self.messages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:(NSDictionary*)response];

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                  [self.tableView reloadData];
             });
         }
         failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, NSError *err) { NSLog(@"failed to get data"); }
         ];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *PointsTableIdentifier = @"MyMessagesCell";

    MyMessagesCell *cell = (MyMessagesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PointsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyMessagesCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    NSDictionary *receivedSubjectLine = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [[cell subjectLine] setText:[receivedSubjectLine objectForKey:@"field_message_subject"]];
    NSLog(@"Received message subject is here %@", receivedSubjectLine);

 return cell;

}
```

**See the returned JSON format below:**

```
 2016-02-02 10:37:19.996 app[4208:1406692] Messages are as follows (
            {
            arguments =         (
            );
            data =         (
            );
            "field_message_body" =         {
                und =             (
                                    {
                        format = "<null>";
                        "safe_value" = "Testing message center";
                        value = "Testing message center";
                    }
                );
            };
            "field_message_group_ref" =         (
            );
            "field_message_subject" =         {
                und =             (
                                    {
                        format = "<null>";
                        "safe_value" = Testing;
                        value = Testing;
                    }
                );
            };
            "field_message_user_ref" =         (
            );
            language = en;
            mid = 1;
            "rdf_mapping" =         (
            );
            timestamp = 1447260780;
            type = "private_message";
            uid = 1;
        }
    )
```

Comment: have u try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534502/ios-loadnibnamed-confusion-what-is-best-practice) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your JSON formatting, accessing field_message_subject should be something like

```
 [[[[receivedSubjectLine objectForKey:@"field_message_subject"] objectForKey:@"und"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"value"];
```

Comment: This looks closer to what I want, but how do I put the cell in this line (the UILabel I want to populate is called subjectLine and it's located in my TableView cell)?

Comment: Use this in cellForRowAtIndexPath like you were doing.  You could set the above to an NSString called messageSubject, underneath  NSDictionary *receivedSubjectLine = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].  Then, [[cell subjectLine] setText:messageSubject].

Answer (score 1):

tableview should know how many cell it needs. 
define this tableviewdatasource method to set number of rows needed.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.messages count];
}
```

by the way if you increment the number of rows you should initialize your self.messages in `viewDidLoad` and add entries withh `addObject:`;

```
self.messages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:(NSDictionary*)response];
```

because this will always allocate new space for your array and its size will always be 1.

**EDIT**

```
    NSDictionary *receivedSubjectLine = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   NSArray * val = receivedSubjectLine[@"und"];
   NSString *textToWrite = val[0][@"value"];
       [cell.subjectLine setText:textToWrite];
```

to write the text in the field `value`

Comment: I've added return [self.messages count], but now the console throws me the error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x132b87040' when I hit my ViewController...

Comment: bacause your `field_message_subject` is not NSString it is also `NSDictionary`

Comment: So shouldn't that line of code I highlighted look something like: ...objectForKey:@"und"] objectForKey:@"value"]; ? I'm just not sure how that line of code would look?

Comment: For example I've pulled this data to a UILabel before, just not into a tableview cell, and it looks like:  self.messages.text = [[[[[self.comments objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"comment_body"] objectForKey:@"und"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"value"];

Comment: Tried your edit - doesn't crash my app, but label is empty... :) ? field_message_subject isn't included?

Comment: did you print the `textToWrite` ? it should be `Testing`. if it is not then there is a problem reaching the field.

Comment: Yep - literally copied and pasted exactly as you have above.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `response`(which is `NSDictionary`) to `self.messages` . No where else in your code you are inserting into `self.messages`. Thus `messages` array will always hold one value. You are trying to fetch object at row index from `messages` array. Thus if number of rows are more than 1, your app will crash as `messages` contain only 1 object.

Comment: At the moment, I've set the tableView to only return one row though?

Comment: Your crash message says it is trying to access index 1, which would be the second row in your table.  Are you sure you are only telling it there is 1 row?

Comment: I've changed it to: I've added return [self.messages count]; but shouldn't the block I've highlighted above look different for retrieving the specified field? eg. something like: ...objectForKey:@"und"] objectForKey:@"value"]; ? I'm just not sure how that line of code would look?